# New to C# and Visual Studio 2008 windows mobile 6.0 sdk

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, accelerometer, windows-mobile-6

Hi does anyone have great examples or any suggestions on Visual Studio 2008 smart device windows mobile 6.0 project coding examples? I'm new to it and wish to develop an app on accelerometer and on Samsung Omnia mobilephone.

Will really be grateful if there's any help from pros around here :). Oh and i have samsung windows mobile SDK installed and have the .cab file already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of developing for desktop and .Net mobile is really barely noticeable. If you can do desktop development you can do mobile .Net development.

The difference lies just in the size of the class libraries. However you will have to see for yourself (Visual Studios Intellisense will only show the available items, to no problem there either).

Comment: Something makes me think you haven't really tried it... "barely noticeable" ?

Comment: I've developed several apps there. Which differences apart from the size of the class libaries are noticable? You can even use the same basic class libraries for UI (Windows Forms) on mobile. Not even Java offers SWING compatible UI elements in MIDP.

Comment: Would be great if there's example codings i could look into